# Make Google Doc into editable form or table embedded in website

Tags: web-development, google-apps, forms

I'd like to make [this Google Doc I've created](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k6auz_44yFZJ1Sd8uGMSoDUSjeqYSprX3JKCjMvxMGc/edit?usp=sharing) into an interactive form or editable table embedded into a website. It needs to be printable on 1 sheet of paper after completion.

I use WordPress, so a plugin would be nice, but if that's too much to ask, what software (i.e. JavaScript) would be a good match for hiring someone to build this for me?